# why can't we override memory priority?

Tags: memory

Is it known why certain information cant be retained by some people even  when it's important to do so? I've read that our ability to remember things   is based on every memory accessed before, priority, interest in the subject,   etc. So why doesn't it always work when you need it to? Like the time/date of   meetings, birthdays, names of co-workers, items you know will be on a test  later.

On the flip side, is it known what mechanism it is that gives a person  (like myself) the ability to remember the same things when generally speaking   it's not something they normally can do with any accuracy? Without really  trying I have little trouble remembering appointment dates/times but ask me   what day something happened a couple weeks ago and i've got nothing.

I hope thats not too much at once. thanks very much

Comment: This seems like an interesting on-topic question. However, rooting the question in a minimal understanding of some related literature (i.e., [different types of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory)) would make it less likely to be closed as ['not framed in psychology or neuroscience'](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2277/21)).